# MISRA:Cast between a pointer to volatile object and an integral type?

Tags: c, casting, misra

I have following code section:

```
----------header---------------------
typedef volatile struct REG_Base{
   a;
   b;
}REG_t

#define address (0xFFF45556)
------------------------------------

--------Source-----------------------

 LOCAL REG_t *pToREG;
 pToREG= (REG_t *) address;

-------------------------------------
```

I got on the last line the MISRA message "**Cast between a pointer to volatile object and an integral type**".

Any idea how to avoid this message?

Thx!

Comment: Don't cast between a pointer to volate object and an integral type. I'm not very familiar with MISRA, but you're probably just doing something it doesn't allow.

Comment: Note: 1) post definition of `LOCAL`  2) The  `volatile` in the `typedef`, IMO, should be dropped.  Then use `volatile` explicitly as needed.  Perhaps then `pToREG= (volatile REG_t *) address;` will work.

Comment: This struct doesn't look like valid C to begin with. What is  `a;` and `b;`, ugly macros?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MISRA has an advisory rule which bans casts from integers to pointers. The rationale is that they are concerned with the poorly defined behavior involved in case the integer cannot represent the pointer, or in case of misalignment.

This is one of the overly pedantic rules and it is just advisory. Most embedded systems will deviate from the rule.

---

That being said, your code contains some questionable things:

- The volatile qualifier should not be part of the typedef.
- The `a` and `b` declarations doesn't make any sense, are they some sort of ugly macros?
- Mapping a struct to a physical address is not portable and safe. The struct might contain padding, the address might not be correctly aligned for the given types. At the very least, you need some means to assure there are no struct padding, preferably a static assert.

Also note that MISRA requires the integer constant to be written as `0xFFF45556u`. This is not a bad idea, because `0xFFF45556` is of type `unsigned int`, while for example `0x7FFFFFFF` is of type signed int. These things might lead to subtle bugs related to implicit type promotions unless you are careful.

Comment: I saw the description in MISRA "However this type of operation is not uncommon in embedded software applications where memory mapped I/O ports must be addressed." This represents my case. The a and b declarations was just dummy declarations which is really not in the productive code. Thank you!